# ExtJS Drag and Drop TabPanel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to drag and drop onto a `TabPanel` tab (The actual tab, not the container) when an attribute is set.

I have a `TabPanel` and am setting up a drop zone across the entire TabPanel strip, but not quite sure about the `getTargetFromEvent`

**Exmple**

```
// My TabPanel Def
myTabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    activeTab: 0,
    items: [{
        title:'Non-Drop Tab'
    },{
        title:'DROP ON THIS TAB',
        enableDrop: True
    }]
});

myTabPanel.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(myTabPanel.strip,{
    getTargetFromEvent: function(e) {

        // ####
        // Need to get the tab being dropped onto here
        // ####

        return the_tab;
    },
    ...rest of config...
})
```

I hope this made sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get Illuminations for Developers (firebug plugin), place a break point into your function override, inspect 'e' object to see what you could use. If your exact target is not available from e then use component query to find your object.